# Has this category of relational structures been studied?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Imagine we define a relational structure as an ordered pair, $(D,R)$, such that the set/class, $D$, is the domain, and the set/class, $R$, consists of relations of various arities over $D$. Now, let's define a category, **RelStr**, with (all possible) $(D,R)$s as its objects, and homomorphisms between such $(D,R)$s as its arrows.

(a homomorphism, $h:(D_1,R_1)\rightarrow(D_2,R_2)$, maps $D_1$ to $D_2$, $R_1$ to $R_2$, and for any ordered $n$-tupe of the elements of $D_1$, like $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$, and any member of $R_1$, like $r$, if $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)\in r$, then $(h(d_1),h(d_2),...,h(d_n))\in h(r)$.)

Now, I wanted to know if anyone's aware of a place where such categories have been studied (even briefly). Based on my very sketchy search in the literature, when people talk about categor*ies* of relational structures, they usually fix a signature, $\sigma$, and take the objects of the category to be $\sigma$-structures. That's why I'm wondering if *the* category of relational structures, in the sense I just defined, has been of any interest to people.

[The other day I posted the above question on Mathematics Stack Exchange, but since I haven't received an answer and it's more like an inquiry about literature, I thought I might need to repost it here.]

Comment: "Categories, Allegories" by Peter Freyd and Andre Scedrov, 1990, North-Holland. ISBN 0444703683

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thanks for this very interesting recommendation.

Comment: "Cats and alligators", as Peter Freyd liked to call it, is not an easy read for someone new to category theory, but it is very precise when you get to understand what it's talking about.

Comment: Crossposted from Mathematics SE: [\*The\* category of relational structures](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4769041)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your structures are precisely $\sigma$-structures for a certain signature $\sigma$,** if I’m understanding your definition right.

The signature has $(1+\mathbb{N})$-many sorts, which we call $D, R_0, R_1, \ldots$, and $\mathbb{N}$-many relation symbols $\rho_n$, where $\rho_n$ is a predicate with domain $R_n \times D^n$.  The idea is that $R_n$ is the set of $n$-ary predicates on $D$.

So a “relational structure” $(D,R)$ in your sense gives an instance of this by taking $R_n$ to be the set of all $n$-ary predicates in $R$, and $\rho_n(r,d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ holds just if $r(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ holds.  Conversely, a structure for this signature gives a structure in your sense by taking $R = \langle \{ \vec d \in D^n \mid (r,\vec d) \in \rho_n \} \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N},\,r\in R_n}$.  Under this correspondence, the maps of $\sigma$-structures correspond to the maps you define, and it gives an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer. To be honest, I was not familiar with the concept of many-sorted signatures. Do you by any chance have in mind any reading suggestions about the category of such structures?